# add a field to registeration to subscribe to newsletter module

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, emails

I want something like the [enewsletter module](https://drupal.org/project/enewsletter) (it is for Drupal 6) for Drupal 7.

I used `simplenews` module, it add a subscribing field to user registration and it is well, but my problem is that in registration user select with category(from favourites taxonomy) want to be subscribe, and in creating simplenews content type select the term that this email send to them,( send simplenews content type according to taxonomy terms ).

I found [simplenews terms module](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews_terms) but it is for Drupal 6.

I try `newsletters` module but it is very complex and doesn't provide something I want.

Comment: "not provide something I want," - unless you tell us what is it, we can't help.

Comment: I want something like simplenews module but user cant select which term of taxonomy subscribing and in creating news select to which subscriber user according to selected term this news will email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `/admin/config/services/simplenews/add` add multiple category you want,
by adding any category here, add term to newsletter category and you can do any thing with its taxonomy